# Variable(s)have been specified in ‘linfct’ but cannot be found in ‘model’!

Tags: r, variables, anova

I want to run a multiple comparisons analysis for the different variables of a model. My idea is as follows:

```
a
   V1   V2
1  t1  5.0
2  t1  4.0
3  t1  2.0
4  t1  5.0
5  t1  5.0
6  t2  4.0
7  t2  3.0
8  t2  4.0
9  t2  9.0
10 t2  3.0
11 t3  2.0
12 t3  3.0
13 t3  2.0
14 t3  6.0
15 t3  8.0

tuk<-glht(fit,linfct=mcp(a$V1="Tukey"))
```

when I run， it showed :

```
“Variable(s) ‘trt’ have been specified in ‘linfct’ but cannot be found in ‘model’!”
```

I don't know how to deal with it。

Comment: In "a", change "V1" for "trt" maybe.

Comment: Do you actually want `glht(fit, linfct = mcp(trt = "Tukey"))`?

Comment: thanks for your suggestions!Pascal &Roland
 
{In "a", change "V1" for "trt" maybe –      Do you actually want glht(fit, linfct = mcp(trt = "Tukey"))?}                   " trt" is the colume name in the data of "cholesterol", which existed in multcomp packages. So changing "V1" for "trt" is helpless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you somehow changed the name of the data and/or the variables between computing your `fit` and calling `glht`. Your code has `V1` but the error has `trt`. It's hard to say more in detail because your example is not fully reproducible (the computation of `fit` is missing). If I re-run what I assume you did (or should have done), everything works smoothly.

First, let's read the data:

```
a <- read.table(textConnection("   V1   V2
1  t1  5.0
2  t1  4.0
3  t1  2.0
4  t1  5.0
5  t1  5.0
6  t2  4.0
7  t2  3.0
8  t2  4.0
9  t2  9.0
10 t2  3.0
11 t3  2.0
12 t3  3.0
13 t3  2.0
14 t3  6.0
15 t3  8.0"), header = TRUE)
```

Then, we can fit what I assume is supposed to be a linear model with response `V2` and explanatory variable `V1`:

```
fit <- lm(V2 ~ V1, data = a)
```

And then the `multcomp` package can be called:

```
library("multcomp")
summary(glht(fit, linfct = mcp(V1 = "Tukey")))
##          Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses
## 
## Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts
## 
## Fit: lm(formula = V2 ~ V1, data = a)
## 
## Linear Hypotheses:
##                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
## t2 - t1 == 0  4.000e-01  1.424e+00   0.281    0.958
## t3 - t1 == 0  5.617e-16  1.424e+00   0.000    1.000
## t3 - t2 == 0 -4.000e-01  1.424e+00  -0.281    0.958
## (Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the problem seems to lie in the way the model is declared. It won't work if you use:

> fit <- lm(a$V2 ~ a$V1)

But it does if you declare the model as:

> fit <- lm(V2 ~ V1, data = a)